# How do I change an array-valued key of a json field in a MYSQL database using JSON_REPLACE and JSON_ARRAY?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm trying to change one of the array-valued keys (called religions) of a JSON field named preferences in a MySQL table.

I'm not using JSON_ARRAY_APPEND because the changes in the field can be arbitrary and can involve both removals and additions.

Right now I'm trying to change it by using the following query.

```
const religionPreferences = ["Buddhism","Christianity","Non religious"]
const sql = `UPDATE users SET preferences = JSON_REPLACE(
    preferences,
    '$.${key}',
    JSON_ARRAY(religionPreferences[0], religionPreferences[1], religionPreferences[2])
)
WHERE id = "${req.params.id}" LIMIT 1`
```

The problem is that the religionPreferences array can have anywhere from 0-14 elements and I wasn't sure how to proceed with variable arguments having to be passed into the JSON_ARRAY function.

```
const religionPreferences = ["Buddhism","Christianity","Non religious"]
const sql = `UPDATE users SET preferences = JSON_REPLACE(
    preferences,
    '$.religions',
    JSON_ARRAY(religionPreferences[0], religionPreferences[1], religionPreferences[2])
)
WHERE id = "${req.params.id}" LIMIT 1`
```

Another approach I tried was just directly setting the argument for JSON_REPLACE as an array literal instead of passing in JSON_ARRAY as below.

```
const religionPreferences = ["Buddhism","Christianity","Non religious"]
const sql = `UPDATE users SET preferences = JSON_REPLACE(
    preferences,
    '$.religions',
    ${religionPreferences}
)
WHERE id = "${req.params.id}" LIMIT 1`
```

The problem is that I want it to be saved as

```
religions: ["Christian","Buddhist","Other"]
```

instead of

```
religions: '["Christian","Buddhist","Other"]'
```

But when I tried to save it as an array directly without quotes around it, it said the SQL had an error..

Thanks so much.
-Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo. First we set up some JSON documents for testing.

```
mysql> set @j = '{"religions": []}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @r = '["Buddhism","Christianity","Non religious"]';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

What you don't want is to treat `@r` as a string, and set it as the value for the "religions" key. This is the default, because otherwise there would be no way to set a value to a string that happens to contain characters that appear like a JSON document.

```
mysql> select json_replace(@j, '$.religions', @r);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_replace(@j, '$.religions', @r)                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"religions": "[\"Buddhism\",\"Christianity\",\"Non religious\"]"} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But if you explicitly cast the value as a JSON document, then you can do what you want. It sets the value for the "religions" key to be a JSON array.

```
mysql> select json_replace(@j, '$.religions', cast(@r as json));
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_replace(@j, '$.religions', cast(@r as json))            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"religions": ["Buddhism", "Christianity", "Non religious"]} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```