# How to set a JSON value with JSON_SET MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I'd like to insert this JSON value ["Chien", "Chat"] in a JSON, with MySQL8 built-in JSON functions.
So I tried with this query but I didn't get the expected output:

```
UPDATE tasks SET outputFields = JSON_SET(outputFields, '$.checkbox', '["Chien","Chat"]') WHERE id = 6832
```

This query made this valid JSON:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "checkbox": "[\"Chien\",\"Chat\"]"}
```

The expected value is:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "checkbox": ["Chien","Chat"]}
```

Is there a function or a work arround for it?

Comment: This is almost the same question as this one which I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622166/how-do-i-change-an-array-valued-key-of-a-json-field-in-a-mysql-database-using-js/69622594#69622594

Comment: It works with Cast function. Thank you Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CAST function like this:

```
UPDATE tasks SET outputFields = JSON_SET(outputFields, '$.checkbox', cast('["Chien","Chat"]' as json)) WHERE id = 6832
```